# Keep getting Force close when I test my app

Tags: java, android

I'm build a app that consist of user login and registration but every time I test it on the emulator I receive a force close. Below are the errors I'm receiving in the log cat:

```
08-14 14:06:28.853: D/dalvikvm(828): GC_FOR_ALLOC freed 108K, 3% free 8262K/8455K, paused 89ms, total 92ms
08-14 14:06:29.273: I/Choreographer(828): Skipped 72 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-14 14:06:29.373: D/gralloc_goldfish(828): Emulator without GPU emulation detected.
08-14 14:06:29.373: D/dalvikvm(828): GC_CONCURRENT freed 5K, 3% free 8660K/8839K, paused 110ms+28ms, total 365ms
08-14 14:06:29.902: I/Choreographer(828): Skipped 85 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-14 14:06:32.533: D/dalvikvm(828): GC_CONCURRENT freed 32K, 3% free 9027K/9223K, paused 81ms+111ms, total 343ms
08-14 14:06:32.813: I/Choreographer(828): Skipped 71 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-14 14:06:33.303: I/Choreographer(828): Skipped 38 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-14 14:06:39.854: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(828): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
08-14 14:06:39.854: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(828):   in android.widget.EditText@412b2f68
08-14 14:06:39.854: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(828):   0: sent at 1614282000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_M, scanCode=50, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1614282, downTime=1614282, deviceId=0, source=0x301 }
08-14 14:06:39.874: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(828): KeyEvent: ACTION_UP but key was not down.
08-14 14:06:39.874: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(828):   in android.widget.EditText@412b2f68
08-14 14:06:39.874: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(828):   0: sent at 1614392000000, KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_TAB, scanCode=15, metaState=0, flags=0x8, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1614392, downTime=1614282, deviceId=0, source=0x301 }
08-14 14:06:39.874: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(828):   -- recent events --
08-14 14:06:39.874: D/InputEventConsistencyVerifier(828):   1: sent at 1614282000000, (unhandled) KeyEvent { action=ACTION_UP, keyCode=KEYCODE_M, scanCode=50, metaState=0, flags=0x80000008, repeatCount=0, eventTime=1614282, downTime=1614282, deviceId=0, source=0x301 }
08-14 14:07:02.362: D/AndroidRuntime(828): Shutting down VM
08-14 14:07:02.362: W/dalvikvm(828): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
**08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828): android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1117)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.connect(BlockGuardOs.java:84)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connectErrno(IoBridge.java:127)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at libcore.io.IoBridge.connect(IoBridge.java:112)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:192)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:459)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:842)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.conn.scheme.PlainSocketFactory.connectSocket(PlainSocketFactory.java:119)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.DefaultClientConnectionOperator.openConnection(DefaultClientConnectionOperator.java:144)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPoolEntry.open(AbstractPoolEntry.java:164)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.conn.AbstractPooledConnAdapter.open(AbstractPooledConnAdapter.java:119)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:360)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:41)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at library.UserFunctions.loginUser(UserFunctions.java:40)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.thryfting.www.LoginActivity.onClick(LoginActivity.java:66)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4084)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:16966)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:615)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:92)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4745)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:786)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:553)
08-14 14:07:02.472: E/AndroidRuntime(828):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)**
```

Updated code for register activity:

```
    package com.thryfting.www;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import library.DatabaseHandler;
import library.UserFunctions;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.actionbarsherlock.app.SherlockActivity;

public class RegisterActivity extends SherlockActivity implements OnClickListener{

    Button btnRegister;
    EditText inputFullName;
    EditText inputEmail;
    EditText inputPassword;
    TextView registerErrorMsg;
    TextView loginScreen;

    //JSON Response node names
    private static String KEY_SUCCESS    = "success";
    private static String KEY_ERROR      = "error";
    private static String KEY_ERROR_MSG  = "error_msg";
    private static String KEY_UID        = "uid";
    private static String KEY_NAME       = "name";
    private static String KEY_EMAIL      = "email";
    private static String KEY_CREATED_AT = "created_at";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.register);

        loginScreen      = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.link_to_login);
        inputEmail       = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etemailSignup);
        inputPassword    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etPasswordSignup);
        inputFullName    = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFullnameSignup);
        btnRegister      = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnRegister);
        registerErrorMsg = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.register_error);


        loginScreen.setOnClickListener(this);
        btnRegister.setOnClickListener(this);

    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch(v.getId()){
    case R.id.btnRegister:

        new register().execute(KEY_SUCCESS);

        break;

    case R.id.link_to_login:
        Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), LoginActivity.class);
        startActivity(i);

        //Close Registration View
        finish();

        break;

        }

    }

    public class register extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

        @Override
        protected String doInBackground(String... params) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            String name = inputFullName.getText().toString();
            String email = inputEmail.getText().toString();
            String password = inputPassword.getText().toString();

            UserFunctions userFunction = new UserFunctions();
            JSONObject json = userFunction.registerUser(name, email, password);

            try{

                if(json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS) != null){
                    registerErrorMsg.setText("");

                    String res = json.getString(KEY_SUCCESS);
                    if(Integer.parseInt(res) == 1){
                        //user successfully registered
                        // Store user details in SQLite Database
                        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());
                        JSONObject json_user = json.getJSONObject("user");

                        //Clear all previous data in database
                        userFunction.logoutUser(getApplicationContext());
                        db.addUser(json_user.getString(KEY_NAME), json_user.getString(KEY_EMAIL), json.getString(KEY_UID), json_user.getString(KEY_CREATED_AT));



                    }else{
                        //Error in registration
                        registerErrorMsg.setText("Error occured in registration");
                    }
                }
            } catch(JSONException e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            } finally{

                //Launch Dashboard 
                Intent dashboard = new Intent (getApplicationContext(), Timeline.class);

                //Close all views before launching Dashboard
                dashboard.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);

                //Close registration screen
                finish();
            } 

            return null;
        }

    }

}
```

New error messages below:

```
08-15 14:53:32.940: W/dalvikvm(865): threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40a13300)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865): FATAL EXCEPTION: AsyncTask #1
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865): java.lang.RuntimeException: An error occured while executing doInBackground()
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.AsyncTask$3.done(AsyncTask.java:299)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerSetException(FutureTask.java:273)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.setException(FutureTask.java:124)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:307)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:137)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.AsyncTask$SerialExecutor$1.run(AsyncTask.java:230)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1076)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:569)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:856)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865): Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Target host must not be null, or set in parameters. scheme=null, host=null, path=register
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.determineRoute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:591)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultRequestDirector.execute(DefaultRequestDirector.java:293)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:555)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:487)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at org.apache.http.impl.client.AbstractHttpClient.execute(AbstractHttpClient.java:465)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at library.JSONParser.getJSONFromUrl(JSONParser.java:41)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:63)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.thryfting.www.RegisterActivity$register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:89)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at com.thryfting.www.RegisterActivity$register.doInBackground(RegisterActivity.java:1)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:287)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:305)
08-15 14:53:33.060: E/AndroidRuntime(865):  ... 5 more
08-15 14:53:34.812: I/Choreographer(865): Skipped 93 frames!  The application may be doing too much work on its main thread.
08-15 14:53:36.512: I/Process(865): Sending signal. PID: 865 SIG: 9




public JSONObject registerUser(String name, String email, String password){
        //building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("tag", register_tag));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("email", email));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("password", password));

        //Getting JSON object
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.getJSONFromUrl(register_tag, params);

        //return json
        return json;

    }
```

Answer (score 3):

Your getting a StrictMode violation. This means that you are doing something blocking on the UI Thread. Hence the reason for

> android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException

From the rest of your LOG it appears your performing a web request.
Make sure that HTTP request is wrapped in an AsyncTask (or something similar)

Comment: And I would recommend against using your own Threads. This doesn't offer methods that run on the UI Thread for you. onPreExecute and onPostExecute Come in handy.

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you are trying to do your login and registration on the main Thread. First of all this is bad practice, and it can't be done on recent API levels. 
All you need to do is make your network connections in a separate thread, be it an AsyncTask or just a plain old Thread()

as an example :

use this

```
public void login()
{
   new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
    //your network connection goes here
    }
   }).start();
}
```

instead of :

```
public void login()
{
    //your network connection goes here
}
```

Comment: I have the login and registration in seperate activities I followed this tutorial right here

Comment: http://www.androidhive.info/2012/01/android-login-and-registration-with-php-mysql-and-sqlite/

Comment: in this tutorial he is using Android 2.2 API level 8. at this API level you can do your network connections on the main thread even though it's bad practice. 
All you need to do is take all your network calls off the main thread by putting them in a runnable and run it in a different thread.
Another option would be to revert back to older API level which will make your current code work but again it's bad practice

Comment: Thank you for all your help, I'm going to try it out once I get home and let you know how it goes

Comment: Hey @Eddyk I added the AsyncTask to my thread. But I think I'm still doing something wrong :/ I posted my new updated code above

Comment: it seems to me that there is something wrong here :
library.UserFunctions.registerUser(UserFunctions.java:63)

Comment: I just posted my register user code can you take a look at it please?

Answer (score 0):

Try to check the same in a mobile with internet connectivity.
The logcat also displays that the emulator doesnt has a GPS connectivity.

Comment: I'm still getting force close on my phone as well